# Use EJS in iOS 8 WKWebView (cross origin request)

Tags: javascript, ios, ejs, ios8, wkwebview

I've got an app on iOS that uses [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com) to render some fancy stuff in web views.  I'm in the process of setting it up to use `WKWebView` on iOS 8, but I'm running into issues.  When I create a new EJS to render:

```
var myjs = new EJS({url: 'file.ejs'}).render({...});
```

I get an error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/hash/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/34E247A4-34F3-4334-99D3-C236715427E6/MyApp.app/file.ejs. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

This worked with `UIWebView` in iOS 6 and 7.  What is going on in 8?  Is this a bug in `WKWebView`, or is there something special I need to do with the path?  I've tried prepending `/` and `~/` to `file.ejs` to no avail.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with ThreeJS. In my case I am using the THREE.JSONLoader that performs an Ajax call and the problem is that the xhr.status code is 0. Seems that XHR is not working on WKWebView

Comment: OK I have realised that status code 0 means cancelled before going anywhere. Probably due to Cross origin request. How did you manage to get that error?